# Stretch background one side out of the grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on the css/html of a website with the framework Boostrap 3.

I have my content aligned on the grid, but two divs have background out of the grid.(one at left, one at right). I don't know how to do this. I mean have the black background full with at right, and the yellow div full width at right.

[The design and the two div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmHB6.png)

How would you do ?
thank you !

Comment: If you post the code we might be able to help

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap is responsive. Put the code where is divs, you probably put wrapper div

Comment: The question is about the background and how to make them full width right, and full width left

Comment: here is bootstrap grid system ---> https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: This post might answer the question, though it is has no meaning full content as _the code_ you suggest could mean anything. The same goes for the question, which make it more or less impossible to answer.